# Conflict in system time format and database return time string value format in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I was using  `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert my date string value to Date object.

Here is the code that I use to convert my date string to `DateTime` object.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(“ my date string value from database ”, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;
```

My database returns a string value like this `“25/9/2016 00:00:00”`.
But when I was debug my code it continuously gave me that string is not valid string to convert to `DateTime` object.

Finality I have to change my laptop date time format to **“d/M/yyyy H:mm:ss”** to make my database string value to valid string value.

So how can I guarantee that my code work in server. What is the solution for this kind of situations ?? Do I have to check server date time format and change to format string according to it before build my code.??

Comment: Why do you store a datetime value inside a string column? This is the problem to solve.

Comment: `25/9/2016` is `dd/M/yyyy`, not `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Depends on way You get data from database, maybe column is DATE type, only for human eyes formatted like here. Show code!!!

Comment: @Steve It is too late to change the Database column type. So what can I do for this situation.

Comment: Never is too late. Such field is totally wrong, bad sorted, impossible to presice queries etc ... conditionally I can accept (in very old systems) date coded in string for example 2016-09-25, but no like here

Comment: Well then you are condemned to suffer the pains of hell with that field. Besides nothing is written in stone. Just add another field of the correct type and write a script that initializes this new field, finally rename the string field. Now your code will crash whenever you try to use the old one and you can evaluate the effort required to fix your code

Comment: @Steve I think I got your point. Thank for the show me way to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParseExact` with the format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" will fail when you give it the string “25/9/2016 00:00:00” because the month is just a single digit.

Changing the format to "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss" is the correct solution.

However, you shouldn't be storing dates & times in your database as strings as you will keep encountering this sort of problem. One of the main causes will be different settings when the date to string conversion happens. The main ones will be day-month-year vs month-day-year and single vs double digits for the days and months. Also if you're converting to local time rather than UTC then events will appear out of order in the database if you have users in different time zones.

If you really have to have strings then you can use the overload of [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx)  that takes an array of allowable formats so you can cope with multiple formats as in the example from that page:

```
  string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                     "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                     "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm",
                     "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff" };
  string[] dateStrings = {"5/1/2009 6:32 PM", "05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                          "5/1/2009 6:32:00", "05/01/2009 06:32", 
                          "05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM", "05/01/2009 06:32:00",
                          "08/28/2015 16:17:39.125", "08/28/2015 16:17:39.125000" };
  DateTime dateValue;

  foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
  {
     try {
        dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                                        new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                        DateTimeStyles.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
     }
     catch (FormatException) {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
     }                                               
  }
```

Comment: Is the database's return string value depending on server time format ?

Comment: @NoughT, If the field is a string then it's purely dependent on the method used to originally convert the date/time to a string. Once it's a string then different server settings will have no effect.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: @ChrisF And it's likely to end up simplest to store UTC datetimes rather than local datetimes.

Comment: Not local / UTC is a main problem here.